# Agm google maps - how to bind latitude and longitude to HTML

Tags: google-maps, binding, angular-google-maps

I am facing a issue in binding the latitude and longitude parameters that I have got from AJAX response. If i hardcode the latitude and longitude in HTML, it works fine. But when i pass the data from response, it just doesnt work.

```
  <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
                <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"></agm-marker>
              </agm-map>

     ngOnInit() {
        this.getTransactionView(this.selectedTransaction);
      }

    getTransactionView(selectedTransaction): void {

        const resultArray = {
          'latitude': '51.525244',
          'longtitude': '-0.141186'
        };
        this.transactionResult = resultArray;
        this.latitude = this.transactionResult.latitude;
        this.longitude = this.transactionResult.longtitude;
       console.log(this.latitude);
      console.log(this.longitude);
// console.log prints the values, but after binding to HTML , it doesnt display the marker
      }
}
```

Comment: Why I am not getting any solution to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it occurs since the provided values of `string` type.

[`AgmMarker`](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/agmmarker) expects `latitude` and `longitude` values of `number` type, for example:

map.component.html:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

map.component.ts:

```
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initData();
  }


  initData(): void {
    this.http.get<{}>('./assets/data.json')
    .subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
      this.lat = parseFloat(result['lat']);
      this.lng = parseFloat(result['lng']);
    });
  }

}
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo-1qwund) for your reference